# Display custom options on category page and allow add to cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, javascript, addtocart, magento2.4.1

I want to display product's custom option on listing page and want to allow customer to add to cart from the category listing page.

I have added Qty field and following code to display the custom option on listing page.

```
           <?php  

    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);
 $optStr = '';
foreach($customOptions as $optionKey => $optionVal):
    //$optStr .= "<div class='custom-options'><label>".$optionVal->getTitle()." </label>";
        $optStr .= "<select name='options[".$optionVal->getId()."]'>";
        foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
        $optStr .= "<option value='".$valuesVal->getId()."'>".$valuesVal->getTitle()."</option>";
            }

    $optStr .= "</select>";
endforeach;
   echo($optStr );

 ?>
```

Using above code custom option  is displaying. But when we add to cart, it's not adding product to cart with custom option and being redirected to product page.

How can I make add to cart with custom option on the category listing page?

any help would be appreciated.